# CSV to Stream of Maps in Elixir

Tags: csv, elixir

I need to parse a large about of `csv` data where the first line of the file is the headers. The library `:csv` already gives me a Stream of lists, I need to deduce the structure from the first line but ignore it and then produce a Stream of Maps with the given structure.

I like this:

**data.csv**

```
a,b
1,2
3,4
...
```

**CSV.stream_map(filename) Output**

```
{a: 1, b: 2} #1
{a: 3, b: 4} #2
...
```

I was looking into `Stream.transform` but couldn't figure out how to skip the first element. The structure can be stored in the accumulator.

Answer (score 13):

If you pass `headers: true` as the second argument to `CSV.decode/2` (as mentioned in the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/csv/CSV.html#decode/2)), it'll automatically use the first row as key names and return a Map for all the following rows.

```
iex(1)> CSV.decode(File.stream!("data.csv"), headers: true) |> Enum.to_list
[%{"a" => "1", "b" => "2"}, %{"a" => "3", "b" => "4"}]
```

`data.csv` contains:

```
a,b
1,2
3,4
```

Answer (score 5):

While the `csv` module already does this as I've found out, I also found a way to implement this myself. It turns out that if you send back an empty list `[]` on the `Stream.transform` callback, no element gets pushed into the stream:

```
def map_stream(enum) do
    enum
    |> Stream.transform(:first, &structure_from_header/2)
end

#The accumulator starts as :first, the its the structure of the csv
#that is the first line
def structure_from_header(line, :first),
    do: { [ ], line } #<=================== Here is the trick

def structure_from_header(line, structure) do
    map = 
      structure
      |> Enum.zip(line)
      |> Enum.into(%{})

{ [ map ], structure }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two options I think. Here you can set the chunk size so you not load the entire file into memory and you can work on sets of it. If you need to parse your data do not use the flow solution. In both I show how to skip the headers. As for creating the maps structure you can take a look at [structs](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html) to then leverage a structure to create structure for your mapsets. If you have lots of columns I would suggest a MapSet and not a map.

```
def stream_parse(file_path, chunk_size) do
  file_path
    |> File.stream!
    |> Stream.drop(1)
    |> Stream.map(&String.split(&1, ","))
    |> Stream.chunk(chunk_size, chunk_size, [])
    |> Stream.map(&MapSet.new(&1))
end

def flow_parse(file_path, chunk_size) do
  file_path
    |> File.stream!(read_ahead: chunk_size)
    |> Stream.drop(1)
    |> Flow.from_enumerable
    |> Flow.map(&String.split(&1, ","))
    |> Flow.partition
    |> Flow.map(&MapSet.new(&1)
end
```